# Jquery form validation - return false doesn't end loop

Tags: jquery

I want to validate a form so that all text input fields are filled up. To do so, I wrote functions below , but my problem is that it always shows me verified message. If I keep some field empty, it shows both empty and verified alert.

If you please help or suggest better method.

```
function validate() {
    $("#myform :text").each(function(){
        if($.trim(this.value).length==0){
            alert("Empty!");
            return false;
        }
    });
    return 1;
}
$(document).on('click','#addnew',function() {
    if(validate() != 1){
        return false;
    }
    alert('Verified.');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `return false;` will only exit out of the `$.each()` loop. You'd need to set a variable in your loop, then return that:

```
function validate() {
    var ret = true;
    $("#myform :text").each(function(){
        if($.trim(this.value).length==0){
            alert("Empty!");
            ret = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

You'd need to then change your `click` handler appropriately (use bools instead of -1);

Answer (score 1):

In your code, any completed field after an empty field would cause your function to return 1.  To get around this, create a variable that is defined as true and set it to false if any field is empty.

```
function validate() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('#myform :text').each(function () {
        if($.trim(this.value).length === 0){
            alert('Empty!');
            isValid = false;
        }
    });
    return isValid;
}
$(document).on('click', '#addnew', function () {
    var isValid = validate();
    if (isValid) {
        return false;
    }
    alert('Verified.');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code to return a variable called fail instead of trying return early from your function.  should work better:

```
 function validate() {
    var fail = false;
    $("#myform :text").each(function(){
        if($.trim(this.value).length==0){
            alert("Empty!");
            fail = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return !fail;
}
$(document).on('click','#addnew',function() {
    if(validate()){  
        return false;
    }
    alert('Verified.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all I find it easier to use console.log for JavaScript debugging instead of alerts (they won't block script execution, making timing a little bit more obvious).

So, it seems like your validate function never actually returns -1, it returns false. Because of this, the comparison in the click function will never be true, meaning that the 'Verified.' alert will always show.